# Can't access element in PyWinAuto using child_window()

Tags: pywinauto, uia

I have a third party application wherein I am trying to automate clicking of a button.
First, I accessed all elements using print_control_identifiers() as follows:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application

app = Application(backend='uia').start('selfService.exe').connect(backend = 'uia', title = 'Citrix Workspace', timeout = 50)
```

The tree that I got was very large as I had put 'uia' in both functions.

I needed the 'User Menu' button which was found at a depth of 17.

```
  `|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Button - 'User menu'    (L1423, T185, R1463, B226)`
   `|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['User menuButton', 'Button5', 'User menu']`
   `|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="User menu", auto_id="id0.19596181806763968", control_type="Button")`
```

However, when I use an object wrapper on that element and send the click_input() function, I get an
pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError error.

Pls help in what I should do to be able to access that button

Expected button to be clicked, instead element was not found.